# How to make R recognize a pair of combined variables in an if or ifelse statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
#create two random numbers and link them to letters
a1r <- sample(1:4, 1)
if (a1r==1) {
a1 <- "B"
} else {
if (a1r==2) {
a1 <- "b"
} else {
if (a1r==3) {
a1 <- "R"
} else {
if (a1r==4) {
a1 <- "r"
}}}}

a2r <- sample(1:4, 1)
if (a2r==1) {
a2 <- "B"
} else {
if (a2r==2) {
a2 <- "R"
} else {
if (a2r==3) {
a2 <- "R"
} else {
if (a2r==4) {
a2 <- "r"
}}}}

#combine the letters
acom <- c(a1,a2)

acom
[1] "R" "b"
```

Now the part I can't get to work, how can I use the variable "acom" in an if or ifelse statement?  I believe I just have the formatting wrong somewhere.  Here's the closest I can get.  For testing purposes I skipped the random part and just created an identically formatted variable:

```
testvar <- c("A","B")
ifelse(testvar=="AB", test1 <- 1, test1 <- 2)

test1
[1] 2
```

How can I format either the original data (keeping the AB reassignment structure) so that it can be used easily as a variable or how can I format the ifelse statement to read the current variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure both match in that order, just use

```
testvar <- c("A","B")
test1 <- ifelse(all(testvar==c("A","B")), 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a1r <- sample(1:4, 1)
a1 <- c( "B","b","R","r")[a1r]  # numeric indexing of vector.

a2r <- sample(1:4, 1)
a2 <- c("B","R","R","r")[a2r]   # same strategy, different vector

acom <- c(a1,a2)
if ( paste0(acom, collapse="") == "RB" ) { # original test would always fail     
             test1 <- 1 } else { test1 <- 2 }
```

Comment: Already got a usable result above, but thank you for pointing out my silly mistake of manually creating the indexing instead of using Rs simple and easy methods - huge time saver!